# how would you texture map a rope?

Tags: texturing, uv, nurbs-surface

I would like to make a rope for a game object (so it should be fairly low poly). I know how to divide a cylinder into segments (K key with Z key) and form it around a nurbs path.

for my game engine (unity) my textures have to be powers of 2 and square, so 128x128, 1024x1024 etc, so it would not make sense to use a huge texture with just a thin line used. i need to use the same square rope segment texture over and over again on each segment.

I would like to texture map a segment of rope to each segment, I'm still playing with photoshop to produce the perfect tileable, seamless rope fragment texture, but assuming I work that out, do I have to select each segment and use the uv smart project on each one, or is there a quicker way to do the whole lot.

Answer (score 4):

1. **Create a bezier curve** in the shape of your rope.
2. **Create a rope segment** with some seamless texture.
   [image]
3. Make sure that the bezier **curve and the rope segment have origin in the same location.**
4. For the rope segment **add Array modifier, set length to Fit curve,
   select your bezier curve** and **tick Merge** so it won't generate vertices doubles.
5. **Add Curve modifier and select your rope segment.**
6. Now you should have something like this:
   [image]
7. **Close the ends** of the rope model.

Comment: thanks but i should have added that my textures have to be powers of 2 and square, so 128x128, 1024x1024 etc, so it would not make sense to use a huge texture with just a thin line used. i need to use the same texture over and over again on each segment. the bit about the making the curved cylinder i already have.

Comment: I would remove the last step. (All though that was the only step that I completed)

Comment: OK, edited, it seems like some fun is not allowed here.

Comment: You can enable 'Merge' on the Array modifier so you don't have to remove the doubles manually.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that feature - thanks, I have edited my answer according to that.

Comment: steveh - I am sorry but don't get your problem. Yhy can't you use your 128x128 texture the same way as in the example I have posted? The texture in the example is also small, square and power of 2 ... it just repeats (tiles) over the whole model.

Answer (score 0):

i think my best options is to create a macro to do the selection and uv mapping, then at least each segment is only one hot key
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMxkU350SaE
i haven't tried it yet, but it looks like a useful thing to use