# How to make realistic looking stitching

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm trying to make a leather belt but can't seem to find a good way to make realistic looking stitches. I'd love to have my stitches look like the image below. **Any ideas how to make realistic stitches?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: How far have you got? Is this for animation (stitches tightening)?

Comment: you could use this kind of solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114563/how-to-create-twisted-wires-in-blender/114566#114566  you just need to add a Curve modifier and also give the good texture to your object so that it looks like a cotton thread

Comment: Related: [how to simulate a rope](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/how-to-simulate-a-rope) and [How to texture map a rope](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68577/how-would-you-texture-map-a-rope) and [How to animate twisting of rope](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32348/how-to-animate-the-twisting-of-a-rope/32499#32499)

Comment: @rob I've got the object done but I don't quite know how to texture it to make it look good enough. It's not for animation.

Comment: @moonboots the texturing is what I need help with. I've added my stitch model to the op.

Comment: Where are you stucked? Choosing a good material or Image texture? You could try many Texture and choose which suits the best. And if thats not problem and if the problem are making that bumps then you can try https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60644/how-do-i-add-a-bump-map-to-a-texture-i-made-in-blender

Comment: @Yash exactly. finding and choosing a good material.

Comment: You can try searching on google like "leather texture"

Comment: But you have to make sure that in that image there's no lighting, glossiness, shadows, etc. It should be a pure image texture. Almost all free one have that stuffs

Comment: Some of the paid sites that provides pure image texture are https://www.poliigon.com/ , https://www.textures.com/

Comment: @Yash the leather is not the problem. I can't find any thread material on the well known material websites.

Comment: you need thread material?

Comment: @Yash yes that's right.

Comment: I think threads are too minute to be noticeable to an eye, there is no need to take efforts on such tiny things!

Comment: Just the twist is looking good enough, just add some diffuse and glossy mix to it, make glossiness too low and tweak and its enough for it!